# Windows Store application BackgroundTask memory leak

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a quite problematic memory leak in my Windows Store application. Since it's leaking even in the background, I think the BackgroundTask causes the leak. The leak is quite serious, building up 150MB in 3 hours or so. Any ideas?

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
    var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("notes.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    string s = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    RefreshTile(s);
    defferal.Complete();
}

private void RefreshTile(string notes)
{
    DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
    XmlDocument tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideBlockAndText01);
    var tileTextAttributes = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    tileTextAttributes.Item(4).AppendChild(tileXml.CreateTextNode(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString()));
    tileTextAttributes.Item(5).AppendChild(tileXml.CreateTextNode(info.GetDayName(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)));

    XmlDocument squareTileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquareText01);
    XmlNodeList squareTextElements = squareTileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    squareTextElements.Item(0).AppendChild(squareTileXml.CreateTextNode(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString()));
    squareTextElements.Item(1).AppendChild(squareTileXml.CreateTextNode(info.GetDayName(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)));

    IXmlNode subnode = tileXml.ImportNode(squareTileXml.GetElementsByTagName("binding").Item(0), true);
    tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("visual").Item(0).AppendChild(subnode);

    TileNotification tile = new TileNotification(tileXml);

    TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
    TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);
    TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tile);

    var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
    string s = loader.GetString("NotepadText");
    loader = null;
    if (notes != null && notes.Trim() != "" && notes != s)
    {
        XmlDocument tile2Xml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideText04);
        var tile2TextAttributes = tile2Xml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        tile2TextAttributes.Item(0).AppendChild(tile2Xml.CreateTextNode(notes ?? ""));

        TileNotification tile2 = new TileNotification(tile2Xml);
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tile2);
    }
    else
    {
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(false);
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : Nevermind, found out what was the problem, and it was actually in another part of the code. I've created a list, assigned one of it's elements to the UI every second. Then, when assigning the new one, it seems the UI didn't release the previous one, so I had a huge amount of lists hanging in the air.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything leaking memory in the above code. Also 150 MB in 3 hours is quite a lot for a background task. How many times is it actually triggered during that period?

You could try doing nothing or disabling the background task to see if it is in any way related to the memory leak.

The best way to go about it, though, is to analyze the contents of the memory after you notice it increase. Since there currently isn't any third party memory profiler for Windows Store apps available (that I know of) you'll need to use WinDbg from [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg463009/). [Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2012/10/15/diagnosing-memory-leaks-in-managed-windows-store-apps.aspx)'s a nice blog post to get you started. Also [this SO answer by Filip Skakun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13730498/197913) might be helpful.

Comment: @Dracor UI not releasing the assigned list could be related to [this bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/761770/metro-apps-with-c-heavily-leaking-memory).