# Cleaning resources/disposing in CustomControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm writing custom control for WinRT / WP8.1 and I'd like to know what's the proper way to clean resources/dispose? I use RX (Events to Observables) and I should manually dispose it - but I'm not sure where to do that (without forcing api client to manually call of `.Dispose()` )?

Comment: The key here is you mention you're using Rx to convert events to observable sequences, if you weren't using Rx where would have you put the event unregister ('-=') in the custom control?, I'm guess but probably in the Unload event.

Comment: I can't see thing like "Unload" event in custom control - If it were available I'd just dispose rx observables there.

Comment: okay so where are setting up the event subscription?

Comment: I inherit from Control and setup events in OnApplyTemplate()

Comment: so why not set an event subscription for the Unloaded event in the OnAppylyTemplate?

Comment: @AwkwardCoder Thanks - I totally forgot about it - i feel like a dumb now

Answer (score 1):

I think that will depend on what resources you have and you can come up with many different strategies that will work better for specific scenarios. You can implement `IDisposable` or you can use `Loaded` and `Unloaded` events to manage the lifecycle of your resources. You might simply not use any resources as soon as you can dispose them. You could expose different methods or a property that specifies which strategy to use to the users of your control so they have the power of choice or make it their explicit call to decide when to clean things up.

Comment: Thanks. As you're developer of winrt xaml toolkit - do you have any tips/tools which could help to track memory leaks in custom controls?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730496/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-in-windows-store-apps